# Randomly generate values for a multidimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, boolean

I want to fill `mask[][]` with 25 rows and columns of random boolean values.

I have `boolean mask[][] = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];` but it isn't working.

(ROWS and COLS = 25)

Comment: There are only two values for boolean variables .. true or false

Comment: What is not working?  The 2D array doesn't exist?  It's filled with the wrong values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Random#nextBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean()) to generate random `boolean` values for your `array`.

Try:

```
Random random = new Random();
boolean[][] arr = new boolean[25][25];
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = random.nextBoolean();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using Random.nextBoolean() that should integrate into your code.

Try:

```
boolean mask[][] = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];

Random rand = new Random(SEED);
for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
        mask[i][j] = rand.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```